# How to disable/hide the tabs inside a bootstrap modal?

Tags: angularjs

I have a bootstrap modal inside that I have Tabs. At present all tabs are displaying. I need to hide/disable the tabs so that at a time only one active tab is displayed. When I click on next and previous button the enabling and disabling action of tabs should take place. Kindly help me

```
<div class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div role="tabpanel">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">first</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">second</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">third</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">First tab content</div>
                </div>
                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="goNext()">Next</md-button>
                <md-button class="md-warn md-raised" ng-click="goPrevious()">Previous</md-button>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">Second tab content></div>
                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="goNext()">Next</md-button>
                <md-button class="md-warn md-raised" ng-click="goPrevious()">Previous</md-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your controller is something like this:

```js
angular.controller('TabController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.tab = 1;

  this.changeTab = function(tab) {
    $scope.tab = tab;
  }

}]);
```

You can add ng-clicks to the tabs anchors and an ng-if (or ng-show/ng-hide if you prefer) to the tab-panes, like this:

```html
<div role="tabpanel"
     ng-controller="TabController as ctrl">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#tab1" ng-click="ctrl.changeTab(1)">
      first
     </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#tab2" ng-click="ctrl.changeTab(2)">
      second
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#tab3" ng-click="ctrl.changeTab(3)">
      third
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">

  <div class="tab-pane active" 
       ng-if="tab === 1">
    First tab content
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane active" 
       ng-if="tab === 2">
    Second tab content
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane active" 
       ng-if="tab === 3">
    Third tab content
  </div>

</div>
```